# Python conditional expression with one branch instead of two

Tags: python, python-3.6

The following lambda returns [empty `""`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) for filenames without a slash (e.g. `"local.txt"`):

```
lambda filename: os.path.dirname(filename)
```

I would like to ensure (in very concise syntax) that the lambda always returns a proper directory name, i.e. `"."` instead of `""`.

Is there more concise way for doing this than the following:

```
lambda filename: os.path.dirname(filename) if os.path.dirname(filename) != "" else "."
```

IMO it would be nice if `os.path.dirname` would not have to be specified (perhaps even evaluated) twice. A conditional expression with one branch instead of two (if such a construct exists) could support come in handy.

Comment: `os.path.dirname(filename) or '.'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of `or`'s coalescing behavior:

```
lambda filename: os.path.dirname(filename) or "."
```